# How Can I Split a String in One Character Increments but also Keep The String between Brackets Intact?

Tags: php, regex

So, say I have string like:

```
abcd[efg]hi[jkl]m
```

What I want is to split the string in such a way that each character is placed in its own index in an array, except for the characters within the brackets. They should remain grouped together. In other words, I want to create an array from the input string as such:

```
[0] => a
[1] => b
[2] => c
[3] => d
[4] => efg
[5] => h
[6] => i
[7] => jkl
[8] => m
```

I know I can split the input string in the way shown below using `preg_split('/[\[]*[\][]/U', $value, -1)`:

```
[0] => abcd
[1] => efg
[2] => hi
[3] => jkl
[4] => m
```

However, I do not know the regular expression I'd need to use to get me exactly what I want. What regular expression will give me my desired solution?

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, you split on every "optionally occurring" square-braced expression.  IOW, if a square braced expression is encountered, split on the whole expression (without consuming it) and if there is no expression encountered, then split on that position in the string.

The pattern can look like either of these:  ([Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0SbQgY/1))

```
~\[([^\]]+)]|~  # (shorter pattern, 44 steps on the sample input string)
```

or

```
~(?:\[([^\]]+)])?~  # (longer pattern, 64 steps on the sample input string)
```

Both preg flags are essential to ensure that no substrings are lost and no empty elements are generated during the process.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lp14L))

```
$string = 'abcd[efg]hi[jkl]m';
var_export(
    preg_split(
        '~\[([^\]]+)]|~',
        $string,
        0,
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'b',
  2 => 'c',
  3 => 'd',
  4 => 'efg',
  5 => 'h',
  6 => 'i',
  7 => 'jkl',
  8 => 'm',
)
```

Pattern Breakdown:

```
~          #starting pattern delimiter
\[         #literal opening square brace
(          #open capturing group
  [^\]]+   #match one or more non-closing square braces
)          #close capturing group
]          #literal closing square brace
|          #OR operator, to allow a match on current position (not a brace expression)
~
```

The literal braces are written outside of the inner capture group so that they are discarded/consumed during the splitting.  Normally, the inner capture group would be consumed as well, but the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag demands that that substring should remain after the splitting.

Comment: @user Dang, I wish you would have pinged me using my name in the comment to alert me that you edited your question.  Answer undeleted.